# Not opening the url in window.open

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a link in the page.On clicking the link the pop up should render with required url.I have the window.open code as follows

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('/action.do?name=aravind&age=19&url=http://astrik.com/click?id=613*B&offerValue=2.9','chatWindow','menubar=1, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600,height=450');return false;">Click here</a>
```

on clicking above link the popup is opening with url upto http://astrik.com/click?id=613*B and offerValue is not showing up in the url of pop up.I need the offerValue to be shown in the url.Any reason for not showing up the offerValue.

Comment: It worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Ybue3/

Comment: Have you tried replacing the * with the code %2a ?

Comment: I replaced & with %26.It worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided URL contains a ? that indicates the start of an argument list. Each argument is separated by an `&`. Thus, for the parser the provided argument list look like this:

`name=aravind`, `age=19`, `url=http://astrik.com/click?id=613*B` and `offerValue=2.9`. They all belong to the request to `/action.do`.

You need to escape the last amp with its URL escape code `%26` like this:

`/action.do?name=aravind&age=19&url=http://astrik.com/click?id=613*B%26offerValue=2.9`

to "bind" the last argument to the astrik URL. Maybe it is also required to escape the second ? with `%3F`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('/action.do?name=aravind&age=19&url=http://astrik.com/click?id=613*B%26offerValue=2.9','chatWindow','menubar=1, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600,height=450');return false;">Click here</a>
```

You must [URL encode](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) your parameters for the "url" value, otherwise they will get appended to the original URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the data parts in url's before using it. In this case the data part url is bugged by the ampersand(&) in the url.

```
var url = encodeURIComponent('http://astrik.com/click?id=613*B&offerValue=2.9');


<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('/action.do?name=aravind&age=19&url=' + url,'chatWindow','menubar=1, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600,height=450');return false;">Click here</a>
```

(or just replace the ampersand, not sure now)